# SWIG custom javacode class method not appearing in JNI

Tags: c, java-native-interface, swig

Using SWIG I'm trying to add a custom javacode method into a class.

The resulting wrapper code contains the method definitions that I want, but the JNI wrapper is missing the method declaration.

In my .i file:

```
%typemap(javacode) MyClass %{
  public byte[] SaveObjectToMemory()
  { 
        return MyClassWrapperJNI.MyClass_SaveObjectToMemory(swigCPtr, this);
  }
%}
```

I would expect my Wrapper JNI to contain the following:

```
public class MyClassWrapperJNI {  
    public final static native void MyClass_OtherMethod1(long jarg1, MyClass jarg1_);
    public final static native void MyClass_OtherMethod2(long jarg1, MyClass jarg1_);
    public final static native void MyClass_SaveObjectToMemory(long jarg1, MyClass jarg1_);
}
```

However the method `MyClass_SaveObjectToMemory` does not appear, how can I have this method declaration appear in the JNI wrapper?

**EDIT:**
After much trial and error I've found that I can add the following to the .i to achieve my expected results:

```
%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  public final static native byte[] MyClass_SaveObjectToMemory(long jarg1, MyClass jarg1_);
%}
```

However is this the correct approach?